# Meaning and origin of the term המקום as one of G-d's names

Tags: words, theology

The name המקום is used as a name for G-d. The word means, literally, "the place". What does this mean when referring to G-d who has no "place"? When did this term originate?

Comment: Is hamakom a name of god that cannot be erased? I suspect we need a different tag, or a tag edit.

Comment: @mevaqesh I'm assuming that msh210 added the tag, not me. You asked a very good question, which I recommend that you ask as a separate question.

Comment: (re the comments) hm... I guess I misadded the tag, thinking it was about God's names in general rather than about those that cannot be erased. I'll undo the edit. But perhaps we should change the tag.

Comment: @msh210 I AM asking about G-d's names, in general.

Comment: If you like an answer, consider marking it correct.

Answer (score 3):

Looking up the word מקום in Jastrow, you can see that he glosses the word (when used as a name of God), as: "the Existence, the Lord". I.e., the root קום / קים denotes the quality of existing.

Comment: `When did this term originate?`

Comment: @mevaqesh, I don't know. I assume it's from the mishnaic period of hebrew.

Comment: Jastrow has a very interesting explanation on this. I'd have to look at the Jastrow, directly. The shoresh is very different. Based on Jastrow's take, the word should be המקיים. Any thoughts to how he makes this explanation?

Comment: @DanF, it seems to be in the same mishkal as: mazon, makhon, malon, etc. Roots that have a weak middle letter (vav or yud). In your comment, you assume that it should be a pi'el / transitive form, but I don't think that's necessary. It could have the basic sense of נמצא קיים which is not transitive.

Answer (score 1):

Bereishis Rabbah 68, Berachos 16a, Yoma 8b-9a all agree that the name originates from the fact that "Hashem is the world's place, but the world is not Hashem's place." That is, due to the fact that Hashem is not physical, by definition He cannot have a place because the term "place" can only apply to something physical.

Comment: See also the beginning of Shaar 3 in the Nefesh Hachayim

Comment: Ok nice edits. Minor point: you write: `all agree that the name originates` how do you know that everyone agrees?

Comment: I didn't say that. I said that those three sources all agree that...

Comment: @Yishai I was not promoting a particular belief, e.g. monotheism, polytheism, pantheism, panentheism, etc., or interpretation I was trying to understand what this answer is trying to say. It seems that I correctly understood what it was trying to say, form DonielF's edits.

Answer (score 1):

This term is explained by the Midrash to mean that God is the "place of the world"

> בראשית רבה (וילנא) פרשת ויצא פרשה סח 
>   ר"ה בשם ר' אמי אמר מפני מה מכנין שמו של הקדוש ברוך הוא וקוראין אותו מקום שהוא מקומו של עולם ואין עולמו מקומו

This could be interpreted broadly, as some sort of corporealism, pantheism, panentheism, or none of the above.

The Akedat Yitschak (Terumah 48) understands the statement to focus on none of the above, but rather is saying that God is the cause of the universe:

> והכוונה להודיעו שאינו מתקומם במקום כמו שיראה מהכתובים המשכינים אותו באהל ובמשכן אדרבא שהוא יתעלה מקומו של עולם. אמנם עדין צריכין אנו להתבונן בטוב כוונתם כי הנה אחר שאחד מתנאי המקום הוא להיותו שוה למתקומם מה לי מקיף ומה לי מוקף מכל מקום שניהם חוייבו להיות בעלי שיעור ותמונה. אלא שכוונתם ז"ל כפי שאחשוב היא לצדדים מה מאותן תשעה פנים שזכר החוקר בספר השמע שיאמר בהם שהדבר בדבר. והוא שיאמר שהחלק בכל. או שהדבר במניע כמו שנאמר שהיושר באדון כי המה ראו כי האדון המישר הדרך והמסדר הצדק אשר בו יעמדו העם כאלו הוא המקום הנאמן אשר הם עומדין בו ונסמכין עליו. וכמו שאמרו (אבות פ"א) על שלשה דברים העולם עומד כי הדברים ההם הם באמת מקומו של עולם והוא עומד בהם.
>
> He notes that saying that God is the location of the world seems corporealist as well. Rather he explains that he intent is to say that God is the basis for the world, that is the cause of the world.

He writes similarly in Shemot (shaar 34):

> ממה שיחייב השכל ויסכים הפרסום הוא שהאל ית' נושא העולם כלו וסובלו בכח בב"ת והוא מה שקיים אותו פי ה' ע"י הנביא באומרו (ישעי' מ"ו) אני עשיתי ואני אשא אני אסבול וכו' והי' מהמבואר כי הוא ית' אינו סובלו ונושאו על ידי משוש כאדם הנושא המשא אשר עליו או כעמוד הסובל הבית כי הוא ית' אינו גוף ולא כח בגוף אמנם יאמר שישא ויסבול על שני פנים. הראשון על דרך האדנות והשררה כמו הסבה אל המסובב שיאמר תשא המסובב וסובלתו ומניעתו. ועל זה הדרך יאמר שהרוכב נושא את מרכבתו. כי מצד שהיא נמצאת על אופן מציאות' והולכת על הדרך ההוא. הנה הוא באמת נושא אותה אלא שהיא נושאת בגוף שלו הנושא האדנות הנמצא בו. וכן יאמר שהאלהים ית' להיותו סבת הסבות כלם הוא נושא העולם כלו וכל הנמצאות אשר בקרבו מקטנם ועד גדולם. כי מציאותו יתברך המציאתם וכלם בעבורו וכמו שאמרו שו"חט (תהלים צ') שהוא מקומו של עולם כי הכל בו ובעבורו

He explains that the idea is not that God is corporeal but rather that he metaphorically bears the world, in that he is the ultimate cause of the universe and that he controls it.

The term is not uncommon in the writings of Hazal. Although it never appears explicitly in Tanakh, the verse is Ester (4:14):

> רֶ֣וַח וְהַצָּלָ֞ה יַעֲמ֤וֹד לַיְּהוּדִים֙ מִמָּק֣וֹם אַחֵ֔ר

Is Midrashically interpreted as referring to God as "hamakom"

Ibn Ezra (Gen. 28:11) writes:

> כי לא מצאנו במקרא שנקרא השם מקום. ואל תשים לבך לדרש ממקום אחר (אסתר ד, יד), כי איננו כלל על השם

For we have not found in Scripture that God is called "hamakom". And pay not heed to the derash on the verse ממקום אחר (Ester 4:14) for it does not refer to the name.

Comment: The only thing I would add would be excerpts from  Nefesh haChaim 3:1-3 https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/נפש_החיים/שער_ג . His spin on panentheism and tzimtzum also includes the notion of G-d putting up with us, as he is the Maqom of the sinner as he is sinning. (Yes, related to an idea in early Tomer Devorah.)

Comment: I just like adding the mussar angle. It makes the answer more meaningful to living, not "just" to the brain.